# module.exports method that interacts with HTML page does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am running an electron app in which my `index.html` page is updated by functions in `scripts.js`.

I'm trying to clean up by `scripts.js` file by 'moving' the functions into separate files within the same `js` directory, but whenever I do that and import that function back into `scripts.js` to run on the `render()` method, it does not work.

For example, I put the `currencyExchange()` function into separate file called `currencyAPI.js`:

```
var currencyExchange = function(){ 
    //code here 
} 

module.exports.currencyExchange = currencyExchange
```

Then, I imported it into my `scripts.js` file:

```
var currency = require(./currencyAPI.js);
```

and then called it in my `render()` function like so:

```
function render(){
    // ...
    setInterval(currency.currencyExchange, 1500)
}
```

However, when running `currency.currencyExhchange`, it says that document is not defined.

Here is the `scripts.js` file in my [app](https://github.com/jadech32/mirrortest/blob/master/js/scripts.js)

Comment: "does not work" tells us nothing. Be more specific.

Comment: @jfriend00 The question is also tagged Electron, which is a npm module that provides a simple Chromium fork with which you can write desktop applications. Electron (inside the BrowserWindow) makes you able to use document and window, for example.

Answer (score 0):

in index.html put a script tag with currencyAPI.js and all functions of currencyAPI.js will available in scripts.js. There is no need for import and export in html pages.

All scripts in html page works as global and script functions and variables are accessible by all other scripts.

so you can use currencyExchange function directly anywhere in scripts.js

Answer (score -1):

Following works for me.

```js
// a.js:
const currencyExchange = function (foo) {
    console.log('currencyExchange(): ', foo);
    return foo;
}

module.exports.currencyExchange = currencyExchange

// b.js
const currency = require('./a');

const render = function() {
    const bar = 'dummy';
    setInterval( currency.currencyExchange, 1500, bar);
};

render();
```

Runnning this...

```
node b.js
```

...outputs this:

```
currencyExchange():  bar
render():  bar
```

Comment: I'd think the OP has extra code which they should share before saying 'it works for me'. That doesn't really help....

Comment: @montrealist, I've updated the question now .. I made a typo in my code in the original exporting of the module, but that is now solved (and has lead to this other problem).

Comment: How and where do you execute `render()` in scripts.js? You may have an issue with the value of `this` being different inside `setInterval`. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#The_this_problem).